# Cannot read property 'add' of null

Tags: paperjs

Hi all something wrong with my programming here as getting an error even though shape is drawn, but I can see it;s not quite right [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.7/S/dVJda8IwFP0rl8JoOmtXBV/qggyfNwZ7tD5kbarBNLekcWNo//vyUdEJC5Tmnpycc26SU6RYy6Mi+jhwU+2jNKqwdvUX01AJXUlOQfFveGdmn609QE6lAjs0q8WxL2CW52lAOuyFEagK2MwtaL9tqYakVKXqO8nMVYokI5Q1Qso1StQU4k6oQ1wq741HZfnzPJSSq53Z0zFSFspSNaiJWxZAIV/a3zMNO2ECM1tPJskY1rGwaXpuRQU8jaxHuCg5ToWqN6BQt0yCo1FqZeF8Hqd+T6Bexip0hEIZkqeQJ3+Xi0vgHTdvXvfFkBAjsebk1Z2qZqrGljhgkSfLq0LI0zlxoDdK3u4qlLG6JgIeYA4+72ps4T7KNMC3DhcXdGeKO+K97noI1+Q8/l/tW0R7qScwPx0vIK6YaY9STjW2cQoNqwzqAvJsAYOzH9yLsG/tU3N28Kp9VGy2wy8=)

```
var circle= new Path.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    position: [200,200]
})

splat= new Path()
splat.fillColor= 'pink'
var count= 20
var length= circle.length
for(var i = 0; i <= count + 1; i++){
    var offset= i / count * length
    const normal = i === 0 || i === count
            ? new Point(0, 0)
            : circle.getNormalAt(offset) * (Math.random() * 50);
        const point = circle.getPointAt(offset).add(i % 2 == 0 ? normal
            : -normal);
            console.log(point)
            splat.add(point)
            splat.smooth({ type: 'catmull-rom', factor: 0.5 });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop stop condition is wrong:
`i <= count + 1` should be either:

- `i < count + 1`
- `i <= count`

Otherwise when `i` is equal to `count + 1`, `offset` value is over `length` value and `circle.getPointAt(offset)` returns null.

Comment: Ah! thank you. I have tried to close the path with '          splat.closed = true' but it seems the first and last points are always at a point and not smooth?